# Вопрос о безопасности - подделка POST-запросов, накрутка голосваний

Tags: php, безопасность

Есть система, которая дает возможность проголосовать - вы нажимаете на кнопку "Поддержать", отправляется запрос на сервер, увеличивается счетчик нажатий. Вопрос заключается в следующем - запрос можно подделать... подскажите как в таких ситуация обычно делают? Я имею в виду в глобальном смысле, то есть не именно для этой системы, а как обеспечить безопасность запросов вообще? Какую хитрость нужно использовать? Что нужно отправлять? Какие токены? Чтобы проверять все это на сервере, не подмена ли это. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В общем случае - никак. Запрос от настоящего пользователя ничем не отличается от запроса бота. Поэтому все онлайн голосования поддаются накрутке. Можно отбрасывать множественные голоса с одного клиентского IP, но это не слишком поможет если голосование действительно захотят накрутить.

Answer (score 2):

Существует много способов от этого защититься (и ещё больше - чтобы обойти :)).
Можно заюзать токен - некая последовательность букаф, которые выдаются только на один запрос. Правда в случае подделки запроса не сильно поможет (но от CSRF вполне годен (тоже обходят)).
Для защиты от голосования можно сделать так (сам никогда голосовалки не делал... что странно, кстати):
В таблице голосования делаешь поле с... ID голосовавших, например. При попытке голосовать (пусть с токеном и вообще - это сам юзер хочет обхитрить систему), вытаскивать это поле, проверять наличие там ID текущего юзера и, если он найден, посылать от ворот поворот.

Comment: Ввод токена заставит бота всего лишь делать два запроса вместо одного. Первый за токеном, второй - за голосом.

Comment: Поэтому я и написал что "не сильно поможет".

Comment: Я понимаю, просто топикастер уже был настроен использовать токены когда задавал вопрос. Не хотелось давать ему ложную надежду :-)

Comment: На что?
Токены помогают - их запросить и получить может только авторизованный юзер, т.е. "Первый за токеном" получит голую форму, без токена.
Но они не защита от накрутки, где сам авторизованный юзер может хотеть накрутить.

Comment: Ни разу не видел системы голосования, которая требует авторизации но при этом позволяет голосовать одному пользователю неограниченное количество раз. Или которая требует авторизации, но не проверяет авторизационную куку в момент учёта голоса.

Comment: @PashaPash, Эмн, что?
Системы разные бывают, где-то могут голосовать все, кому не лень (там накручивай сколько влезет - пару прокси и обход готов), где-то только авторизованные (там чуть сложнее - нужно добыть/зарегать акки и прокси), делать голосовалки доступными только через время/репу/сообщения - единственно реально помогающее средство.

Comment: а как именно используют токены? шифруют логин+пароль? вешают на куки или на сессии, потом при каком-либо запросе проверяют этот токен.. я правильно понимаю??

Comment: где-то видел, было написано, нужно еще добавить соль айпи, время и т.п. но как потом это дело расшифровать? то есть сравнивать на сервере

Comment: как вообще случайно сгенерированный токен проверять??

Comment: Токен сделать легко - создаёшь токен на основе времени (удобная штука для "случайных" значений) и псевдослучайной генерации `mt_rand()`, время и рандом шифруешь, например, `MD5`. Отдаёшь юзеру и пишешь его в БД. При обращении с токеном, ты просто проверяешь - есть ли такой токен в БД? И всё.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше невидимую капчу использовать (если видимую нежелательно показывать) Спасает, правда, только от простеньких ботов, но токены в таком виде и от них вряд ли спасут

Comment: @BOPOH, Невидимую капчу? Это вроде как оксюморон :)

Comment: Раньше не слышали? Вот [один из примеров](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972507). Иногда через JS делают - типа того же токена, только поле заполняется/очищается через JS. Бот скорее всего простой будет, поэтому не сможет выполнить JS-код, следовательно отправленная им форма будет невалидной. Еще как вариант - давать полям произвольные имена, в коде располагать в произвольном порядке, а на сайте выравнивать через CSS. На сервере мапить их как следует и проверять. Тогда боту не понятно будет куда следует вставлять наш токен. Вариантов куча если фантазия работает )

Answer (score 2):

Ответ "в глобальном смысле" уже дали - **НИКАК**.

Судя по странным ответам, эту простую истину понимают не все. А точнее понимают, но как-то не до конца. В итоге получаются бессмысленные ответы вида "Токены не помогают, но вот как их реализовать...".

Если же говорить о защите голосования, то здесь есть только две стратегии:

1. Либо вообще никак специально не защищаться, просто ставить куку для
   удобства уже проголосовавших, а потом по логам отсекать накрутчиков.
2. Либо вводить уже тяжелую артиллерию типа капчи смс-голосования.

Середины - это важно понимать - не существует. 
Все эти игру в бирюльки с токенами и IP совсем не затруднят ботоводов, но только затруднят их отлов.

Answer (score 2):

Никак, хотя бы потому, что все методы взламываются очень легко:
1. Фильтр по IP: Заведите бота через TOP - новый запрос, новый IP;
2. Фильтр по токену: Бот просто будет делать два запроса;
3. Капча: Зависит от сложности, простая подбирается на ура, сложная плоха для юзабилити.

Так что вы можете только использовать все три метода в надежде, что накрутчик не обработает их все. Так же в качестве усложнения могу предложить вариант, очень похожий на токены.
При заходе на страницу генерируется сессия, в сессии генерируете уникальный ID (можно просто увеличивать на 1 от предыдущего). При запросе без сессии возвращать, что голос успешно отправлен, но на деле не отправлять его. При запросе с сессией проверять ID, было ли голосование с него, если было, то возвращать ошибку.
Но это лишь легкая маскировка работы с токенами.

Comment: "Фильтр по токену: Бот просто будет делать два запроса" - как это понять??

Comment: Первый запрос на получение токена, второй запрос уже голосование с токеном.

Answer (score 1):

Мне на ум приходит гугловская рекапча. По своим логам не раз видел, что она отрубает некоторых "вредных" посетителей.

Answer (score 1):

Самый удобный как вебмастеру, так пользователю способ отличить человека от бота - сделать что-то наподобие скрытого поля в form-е для отправки запроса, заполняемого javascript-ом. Чтобы подделать такой запрос, понадобится полнофункциональный браузер.

К сожалению, боты, способные на эмуляцию джаваскрипта и продвинутое изображение из себя браузера тоже иногда встречаются. От них этот способ не спасет. Как вариант борьбы с такими товарищами можно усилить ограничения по отправке с одного IP-адреса и блокировать прокси, висящие в blacklist-е IP-адреса, соответствие часового пояса IP-адресу, соответствие его IP-адресу, сообщаемому плагинами, соответствие IP-адреса DNS-у... Но даже все это можно обойти. К сожалению, универсальной защиты нет.

Даже CAPTCHA вас полностью не спасет - даже самую сложную капчу сможет расшифровать китаец за четверть цента =)

Другое дело, что если ваш ресурс не особо популярен, то на него, скорее всего, не забредут даже набиватели голосов с ботами, эмулирующими браузер. Так что излишняя паранойя вам тоже ни к чему.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть лояльная аудитория, которая совершает какие-то действия на сайте, то можно учитывать голоса разных людей с разным весом.

Например, на IMDB голос только что зарегистрированного будет значить меньше, чем голос старого пользователя с похожей на человеческую активность в течении года. Это сложнее обойти, чем токены и IP.